# Plotting multiple categorical variables in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot

I am attempting to make a graph comparing max, min, and mean temperatures from 2 different locations (2 unique locations: turnbull and finley) in R's Plotly package. I have been able to build scatter plots for each location independently, but cannot figure out how to plot both sites on the same graph. Here is a link to the data set (referenced as temp_c in the code): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A1HkOVjifYRp62fkMO2Xe8_STzo2rfq4UXfso9kjxfw/edit#gid=0

[image]

Here is my code for one of the locations - I would like to plot both locations on one graph:

```
fig_fin_1 <- plot_ly(temp_c[temp_c$location=="finley",], x = ~date, y = ~max_temp_c, 
                   type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
                   line = list(color = 'transparent'),
                   showlegend = FALSE, name = 'Finley Max') 
fig_fin_1 <- fig_fin_1 %>% add_trace(y = ~min_temp_c, split = c("finley"), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
                                 fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)', 
                                 line = list(color = 'transparent'),
                                 showlegend = FALSE, 
                                 name = 'Finley Min') 
fig_fin_1 <- fig_fin_1 %>% add_trace(x = ~date, y = ~ave_temp_c, split = c("finley"), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', split = c("finley"),
                                 line = list(color='green'),
                                 name = 'Finley Mean') 
fig_fin_1 <- fig_fin_1 %>% layout(title = "Historical Average, Min and Max Temperatures for Finley NWR",
                              paper_bgcolor='rgb(255,255,255)', plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
                              xaxis = list(title = "Date",
                                           gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                                           showgrid = TRUE,
                                           showline = FALSE,
                                           showticklabels = TRUE,
                                           tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
                                           ticks = 'outside',
                                           zeroline = FALSE),
                              yaxis = list(title = "Temperature (degrees C)",
                                           gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                                           showgrid = TRUE,
                                           showline = FALSE,
                                           showticklabels = TRUE,
                                           tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
                                           ticks = 'outside',
                                           zeroline = FALSE))

fig_fin_1
```

I've tried adding all the traces from each graph into one graph - I'm not sure how to retain the 2 unique colors representing the locations colors when I do this, and I get a strange 3rd line. I've also tried making a new data frame for each location and temperature treatment/measurement (i.e. turnbull_min_c), but that didn't work - here's my attempt at making graph representing both locations:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Photos of data are not useful. I'm going to put together some content to answer your question. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Update

I guess I misunderstood. You want to combine the graphs, not recreate the graph you provided a picture of. I've tried various ways to make this happen. I've only found one method that works every time.

The data I originally created was so similar that you couldn't see them when they were on the same graph. I modified that data (`df1` described in the original answer).

```
# mod so stack is more obvious
df1$min_temp <- ifelse(df1$location == unique(df1$location)[1],
                       df1$min_temp - 5, df1$min_temp)
df1$max_temp <- ifelse(df1$location == unique(df1$location)[1],
                       df1$max_temp - 5, df1$max_temp)
df1$ave_temp <- ifelse(df1$location == unique(df1$location)[1],
                       df1$ave_temp - 5, df1$ave_temp)
```

I used the same `map` call to create `plt1` and `plt2`. (Although, you could remove the `%>% layout` and just add it at the end.)

> I should point out that I reduced the opacity for the blue fill from .2 to .1 so that you could see it overlapping the green (otherwise, it was hard to tell that's what happened).

Then I extracted the trace data from each of these plots so that I could make all of the fill traces first.

```
plt1 <- plotly_build(plt1)
plt2 <- plotly_build(plt2)
plt1_d <- plt1$x$data # extract all trace data
plt2_d <- plt2$x$data
# restack trace data so all fill traces are first
ndata <- list(plt1_d[[1]], plt1_d[[2]], plt2_d[[1]], plt2_d[[2]],
              plt1_d[[3]], plt2_d[[3]])
```

Now that `ndata` is the new lineup of traces, I replaced the data in `plt1`.

```
plt1$x$data <- ndata
```

If you kept the layout in the `map` call (or in your original plot traces you won't need to call the layout again. If you removed it up to this point, you can add it now.

```
plt1 %>% 
  # your original layout (I've changed nothing here)
  layout(title = "Historical Average, Min and Max Temperatures for Finley NWR",
         paper_bgcolor='rgb(255,255,255)', plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
         xaxis = list(title = "Date", gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                      showgrid = TRUE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE,
                      tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)', ticks = 'outside',
                      zeroline = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(title = "Temperature (degrees C)",
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                      showgrid = TRUE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, 
                      tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)', ticks = 'outside',
                      zeroline = FALSE))
```

[image]

---

##### Original answer

I'm assuming from what little I know about your data that the field `location` has two unique values, and that's what you're splitting the graphs with.

You didn't include data, so I've included the data I used in this answer.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

lows <- c(seq(-10, 20, length.out = 7), seq(15, -10, length.out = 5))
highs <- c(seq(0, 30, length.out = 7), seq(25, 0, length.out = 5))
set.seed(25)
df1 <- map2(1:12, rep(c(31, 30), 6),
               function(j, k) {
                 max_temp <- rnorm(k * 2, highs[j], 1)
                 min_temp <- rnorm(k * 2, lows[j], 1)
                 m <- matrix(c(max_temp, min_temp), nrow = 2, byrow = T)
                 ave_temp <- colMeans(m)
                 data.frame(ave_temp = ave_temp, max_temp = max_temp, 
                            min_temp = min_temp)
               }) %>% bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate(dat = rep(seq.Date(from = today(), by = 1, length.out = 366), each = 2),
         location = rep(c("A", "B"), 366)) %>% 
  select(dat, location, everything())
head(df1)
```

I used `map`, but `lapply` does the same thing. This creates 2 separate plots, one object is `plt1`; the other is `plt2`.

```
map(1:2,
    function(i) {
      df <- filter(df1, location == unique(df1$location)[i]) # filter for subplot
      # the area first
      p <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "lines", df, x = ~dat, showlegend = F,
                   y = ~min_temp, line = list(color = "transparent")) %>%
        add_trace(type = "scatter", mode = "lines", df, x = ~dat, 
                  y = ~max_temp, fill = "tonexty", 
                  fillcolor = c('rgba(0, 100, 80, .2)', 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .2)')[i],
                  opacity = .2, line = list(color = "transparent")) %>%
        # line only 
        add_trace(type = "scatter", mode = "lines", df, x = ~dat,y = ~ave_temp, 
                  line = list(color = c('rgba(0, 100, 80, 1)', 
                                        'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)')[i])) %>% 

        # your original layout (I've changed nothing here)
        layout(title = "Historical Average, Min and Max Temperatures for Finley NWR",
               paper_bgcolor='rgb(255,255,255)', plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
               xaxis = list(title = "Date", gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                            showgrid = TRUE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE,
                            tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)', ticks = 'outside',
                            zeroline = FALSE),
               yaxis = list(title = "Temperature (degrees C)",
                            gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                            showgrid = TRUE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, 
                            tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)', ticks = 'outside',
                            zeroline = FALSE))
      assign(paste0("plt", i), p, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    })
```

Now all you have to do is stack them.

```
subplot(plt1, plt2, nrows = 2)
```

[image]

The image of your desired outcome doesn't have x and y-axis labels, but you designated them in your layout. As you can see here, there are no axis labels in the subplot. There is a way to add them via Plotly, but it's much easier to do with the `htmltools` library.

Using this method, you may not want each graph to have a title.

```
plt2 <- plt2 %>% layout(title = "")
```

Additionally, the default height via Plotly is 400 px. The default width is 100%. Because of the height, you lose the dynamic resizing. So first, let's change that.

```
plt1$sizingPolicy$defaultHeight <- '100%'
plt2$sizingPolicy$defaultHeight <- '100%'
```

Now using `htmltools`, stack them.

```
browsable(
  div(div(plt1, style = "width: 100%; height: 49%; float: left;"), 
      div(plt2, style = "width: 100%; height: 49%; float: left;"),
      style = "width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help with this! I am new to SO and apologize for my unclear question.  Yes, I have 2 unique values for location (finley and turnbull) and I am trying to plot 3 variables for each (average, minimum, and maximum temperature; i.e. finley max, turnbull max, finley min, turnbull min, etc) for each. I was able to make two subplots of these data (a plot for each location) as you've done above, but I'm unable to put both locations on one graph. Ideally I'd have 6 lines on a single graph with two unique colors representing the location.

Comment: I have updated my original post to help clarify. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. Sorry about that. You want them on the same graph. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help - I really appreciate the time you took to answer my question :)